# for loop with different order in C#

Tags: c#

I want to go over all the numbers between 2 specific numbers (excluding the 0) and I want to go over them not from the smallest to the largest or vice verse, by from the closest to zero to the farthest.

If my defining numbers, for example, are `-4` and `3` then I want to go over the numbers in the fallowing order: `-1`,`1`,`-2`,`2`,`-3`,`3`,`-4` or `1`,`-1`,`2`,`-2`,`-3`,`3`,`-4` (doesn't matter which of the two). In other languages I can do this with a `foreach` loop, how can I implement it in C#, if the answer is as I suspect a `foreach` loop, how do I construct the list for it?

For example, in Tcl I would do it like this:

```
# num1 is the abs value of the negative limit
set l [list ]
for {set i 1} {$i <= [max $num1 $num2]} {incr i} {
    if {$num1 >= $i} {
        lappend l [expr -1 * $i]
    }
    if {$num2 >= $i} {
        lappend l $i
    }
}

foreach num $l {
    puts $num
}
```

Comment: Show the code you use in other languages, and we can help adapt it to C#.

Comment: You say you want to iterate over a sequence created by two defining numbers, but your Tcl example shows a hardcoded sequence. Either way, my answer deals with both "generating" the sequence as well as skipping zero, so you might wanna give it a check.

Comment: Now the code is not hard coded, I just removed this part before, because I wanted to know what data type to use in C#, not the algorithm to find the numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Linq to order a list by the return of a function.

```
foreach (int x in list.OrderBy(i=>Math.abs(i))
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Won't this change the values he is getting? Instead of -1, wont he get 1 once the abs is done?

Comment: @JeremyK No.  It's sorting on the value returned by the selector, but the output sequence returns the source objects, not the selector's result.  This is immediately obvious if you have a compiler from the data type of the return value assuming the function used in `OrderBy` doesn't return the same type it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();

// Add items to list
// i.e. values.Add(-1);

values.Sort(delegate(int n1, int n2) { return math.Abs(n1).CompareTo(math.Abs(n2)); });

foreach(var num in values)
{
// Do work
}
```

Comment: That's great, but requires hardcoding the values. I think he's looking for a generic approach.

Answer (score 1):

You picked an answer that doesn't matched what you stated in your question.

```
int a=-4, b=3;

var list=Enumerable.Range(1, Math.Max(Math.Abs(a), Math.Abs(b))).SelectMany(x => new[] { x, -x });

foreach(var num in list) {
    Console.Write(" {0}", num);
}
```

However, what matched you really want is more important. I often do not describe my question correctly at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The translation of your Tcl function into C# is straightforward:

```
 var l = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Max(num1, num2); i++) {
  if (num1 >= i) {
   l.Add(-1 * i);
  }
  if (num2 >= i) {
   l.Add(i);
  }
 }
 foreach (int num in l) {
  System.Console.WriteLine(num);
 }
```

A list of integers is `List<int>`. `for` is `for`. Incrementing a variable is `++`. Appending to a list is `Add`. And `foreach` is `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
int startnum = -4;
int endnum = 3;
foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(startnum, (endnum - startnum) + 1).OrderBy(n => Math.Abs(n))) {
if (x == 0)
   continue;

// Do stuff
}
```

Just don't forget to make `endum` greater than `startnum` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = 5;
for (int i = 1, flip = 1; i < max; flip = flip ^ 1, i =  i * -1 , i = i + (flip == 1 ? 1 : 0) )
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This should fix you right up.
It is almost a normal for loop with just a few extra counters / conditions.

flip = flip ^ 1 : The flip variable just flips between 1 and 0.
i =  i * -1 : Every loop through we change the sign to get the desired alternating number
i = i + (flip == 1 ? 1 : 0) : We only increment the counter if it is a positive number.

-- Sorry this doesn't even answer the question. I skimmed the question and came up with this.